# Ask questions about job posting, or just apply?

Tags: applications

I was browsing some job postings, and came across some weird combinations of skills and experience. The job posting of my interest is in-house on the company web site, so I would expect the poster to know the exact requirements, yet it reads:

> Required skills
>
> - Very good programming skills in C#.
> - Deep knowledge of software design and architecture
>
> ...
>
> WORK EXPERIENCE
>
> We encourage professionals with development-related work experience to apply for this position

While many job postings are a mumble-jumble of buzzwords, in my experience these are mostly from independent headhunters, not in-house.

I don't see how one would develop very good programming skills in C# and deep knowledge of software design and architecture, without ever having development-related work experience. Is it appropriate to ask them about this, to get a better understanding about their requirements?

Comment: Would whatever answer they give actually matter to you? One may be able to ask for clarification over significant details, if they would affect whether you apply, but your question sounds like you'd just be nitpicking - I can't imagine that will come across well.

Comment: Just apply. Ask questions during a phone screening, if it gets to that point.

Comment: I think you are overthinking this. *I* read: "No tire-kickers, please". Or in other words "deep knowledge of software design and architecture" could as well be somebody just graduated from uni. They want someone with field-experience.

Answer (score 3):

The wording on the "WORK EXPERIENCE" section of the posting is a little clumsy but I've seen far worse and it's not uncommon to leave some ambiguity when listing required experience since it's far from an exact science.

Regarding the difference between recruiter and in-house postings as ever YMMV but in my experience many of those vague recruiter-posted listings have either come verbatim from the employer or the requirements from the company have been *exceptionally*  vague resulting in the recruiter applying scatter-gun buzzwords to make sure the net is cast wide enough. So it's not really a surprise to see an in-house posting be a bit on the wooly side.

For the posting as-written, to me that reads as them preferring candidates with development-related experience but the lack of explicit exclusions for those that don't would probably mean that if I were a candidate who had acquired the required skills outside of a work environment (through academia, personal projects etc) then I'd probably apply and look to clarify if any experience requirements are non-flexible as part of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to think about...

First, the requirements listed are vaguer than they should be, to be sure.  However, you can glean some information from them.  They appear to want someone who is not new to C#, someone with a shallow learning curve.  Likewise, someone who has experience in software design.  These are specific domains.

**Recommendation:  Were I you, I would approach whoever is the contact for the position, and ask for clarification.**  Tell him or her that you are not sure if your qualifications are what they are looking for, and that you'd like to spend a few minutes to talk it through.  That should clear up any confusion right quick.

Side-note:  I see you have snuck in an entirely separate question, about how to apply for a job which you *know* you lack some of the requirements for.  ;D  That could be a whole separate post, but I'll sneak in a mini-answer here.

Again, talk to the primary contact for the position, explain the situation, *along with what you feel you bring to the table to counteract the deficiency*, or at least your plan to mitigate it.  Frex:  If you don't have as much C# as they ask for, you should be working on a side project in C# (which you can demo) to come up to speed.